# Compare a string read by network stream

Tags: c#, sockets, stream

I'm programming a telnet admin system that request to user to input a command.

I can read it from the socket with a network stream but when I compare the string to another I can't get a match, i have tried Regex..

So here is my code:

```
while (!bit.Contains("\r") && !bit.Contains("\n") && !bit.Contains("."))
{
    bit = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    outputString += bit;
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
}

 // Read till user input ENTER

if ( outputString == "$edit" )
     // do something
```

Comment: Have you debugged through to see what `outputString` contains once the user has hit `Enter`?

Comment: yes i have debuged it, if the user input "edit", in the debug. outputString have "edit", but the if statment can't compare.

Comment: Well, `"edit" != "$edit"`. They are different strings.

Comment: Nice response. You provide an example that is at odds with your code and when this is pointed out all you can think of responding with is profanity and insults. This is not acceptable behaviour on Stack Overflow. I suggest you calm down, grow up and start treating the people _you_ are asking for help from with a modicum of respect and civility. I, for one, will not bother with trying to help you any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that you must move first line of the loop:

```
// init bit variable here
while (!bit.Contains("\r") && !bit.Contains("\n") && !bit.Contains("."))
{
    outputString += bit;
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);

    bit = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean but that code doesn't work for me.

Comment: Tell me how you initialized bit variable? For example if you have declared `char bit = 0;` before the loop, it's the source of your problem.